# ARImageTrackingConfiguration keeps adding many unknown ARAnchors

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am creating a RealityKit app with `ARImageTrackingConfiguration()` as I only need to track images. I have everything set up properly, but when I do the following in my didAdd anchors:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {                
         guard let validAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {
             print("Anchor is not a valid ARImageAnchor")
             continue
         }
    }
}
```

I get loads of output in the console Anchor is not a valid ARImageAnchor as if many ARAnchor's were being created. I would like to understand why that can happen since I'm using ARImageTrackingConfiguration and therefore only image anchors should be created and whether there's something I can do to avoid? Can it cause any potential memory problems?

This is my setup:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
    // Create the ARView instance.
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    // Store a reference to the ARView instance in the ViewModel.
    vm.arView = arView
    
    // Set the session's delegate to the Coordinator class.
    arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    // Create a new ARImageTrackingConfiguration.
    let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
    
    configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true 
    configuration.trackingImages = vm.arReferenceImages 
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1 
    
    arView.session.run(configuration)
    
    return arView
}
```

Comment: What type of anchor are they?

Comment: I added type(of:anchor) to the print and they are AREnvironmentProbeAnchor. I thought these appear only in ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and not in ImageTrackingConfig... Are they any potential memory problem or can I just ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely nothing to worry about. `AREnvironmentProbeAnchor` are an anchor added automatically for [lighting information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arenvironmentprobeanchor) by generating textures from the scene. There are a variety of anchors added to an ARView, that you can either respond to, or safely ignore.

I suggest changing your didAdd Anchors code to something similar to:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {                
         if let validAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
             //act on anchor here
         } else {
             //Anchor is not a valid ARImageAnchor
         }
    }
}
```